# What if the user input exceed the number of characters set in a character array?

Tags: c++, c

I can't find any explanation for this any where. So the question is What if the user input exceed the number of characters set in a character array?

```
int main()
{
    char name[2];
    gets(name);
    puts(name);
    return 0;
}
```

I expected when I typed in more then 2 characters to get a error back or for the program to crash but it takes in about 10 characters still. More then 12 characters crashes it though. What is going on here how does this work?

Comment: This is why `gets` was deprecated (and then removed in C11).

Comment: Also, how does this have to do with C++? (in other words, "natural" C++ would not look like this at all since you would use `std::string` instead).

Comment: 'I can't find any explanation for this any where' - why is it that I don't believe you at all?

Comment: Maybe it's because I Googled the title of your question and got 'About 36,600,000 results'.

Comment: Bseides, 'I can't find any explanation for this any where' at the start of a question with easily available answers means 'write me a unique homework answer that none of the other students have already copy/pasted'.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about 'I can't find any explanation for this any where' despite the hundreds of SO dups re. overwriting the end of C arrays and Googling the title gives: 'About 36,600,000 results'.

Comment: Bound checking is not done in C.

Comment: "*...  typed in more then 2 characters ...*" you'll be provoking undefined behaviour already when typing more then **1** character as in C "strings" imply a `0`-terminator which need 1 char space.

Comment: I don't know man I just couldn't find any answers to this Martin James. You don't have to believe me you believing that I couldn't find it isn't gonna change the fact that I couldn't find it :\

Comment: Why is this question getting downvoted?   It's basic, but it is clearly worded, on-topic, and informative...

Comment: @BadZen and unresearched..

Comment: @MartinJames Who are you to say it was not researched? You're not here with him as I do these things. I just wanted to get a better understanding of this aspect of C coding It's ok to have you're opinion but you are insulting and harnessing me now please stop. I don't know what you get of of bashing me. Go spend time with your family or something find something better to do.

Comment: 'Who are you to say it was not researched?' - because I tried it in the most obvious way and it worked straightaway.  Bashing?  I merely pointed out that googling would generate an answer quicker than asking a question on SO.  Searching on SO first would also have provided many answers.  Why are you so intent on trying to get SO contributors to rehash readily-available information?

Answer (score 3):

You'll overwrite the buffer and cause undefined behavior. This may lead to the program crashing, other variables having altered values, or any number of other problems.

This function has been [deprecated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation) since C++11 and C99. It was removed in C++14 and C11.

Answer (score 3):

gets() is considered dangerous.   This is because it does not check for exactly the sort of condition you're talking about.  If the user input is longer, the behavior of your whole program is undefined.  It might crash, segfault, or print out the entire works of William Shakespeare and still be valid behavior according to the language spec.  So, please use C++ style io or fgets() instead!

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you said right now is the reason gets() is not used.

you should use fgets() instead

```
char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)
```

str = pointer to the memory where you want to store the string

n = maximum number of characters that should be read

stream = pointer to a file object from where the characters are to be read. (to get from the user, use stdin here, i.e. standard input(keyboard))

Comment: Note: Maximum number of characters that should be read is `n-1`.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a buffer overflow. The first two characters will be correctly stored in the array, after that memory on the stack that is not owned by the array will be overwritten. The reason it crashes after a certain point (12 characters in your example) is that it's starting to overwrite system information on the stack that is necessary for the execution of the program. This is an extremely serious (not using the word "extreme" lightly here) security issue, which is why the `gets` function should never be used.

If you'd like more information about what exactly is going on and the security issues involved, I recommend reading this paper: [Smashing the Stack for Fun and Profit](http://phrack.org/issues/49/14.html)

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't do any bounds checking on array accesses, and `gets` has no way of knowing how big the target buffer is, so if you enter more characters than the target buffer is sized to hold, `gets` will happily write those extra characters to the memory immediately following the end of the buffer, which may have any of the following effects:

- overwrite the value in another variable (which can lead to *really subtle* problems that take days to chase down);
- overwrite program state information saved on the stack (a tried-and-true malware exploit);
- a memory access violation;
- no visible effect whatsoever (*something* will get clobbered, but whatever it is isn't "important").

`gets` was deprecated in C99 and has been removed from the C2011 standard altogether; it *will* introduce a major point of failure/security hole in your code.